# how find objects between two labels in clearcase

Tags: find, clearcase

I would like to get all sources/objects between two releases that happened within a month from clearcase. I wrote the below command and it displays only less number of sources compared to the actual one.
Please advive where I am wrong

```
cleartool find <path> -element "lbtype (Label b) && ! lbtype(label a) && ! -element (.../Branch1/latest)" -print
```

where:

- label `a` is the label of last month release
- label `b` is the current label
- and `branch1` is the branch from where all release happened

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To see in general what has changed between two dates:

```
cleartool find . -version 'created_since(10-Jan) && !created_since(11-Jan)' -print
```

But in your case, you missing probably a '**`_sub`**' directive (see **[find examples](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rcss=faqtt_1Q09&uid=swg21124425)** for more requests):

> When the type being queried does not apply to the "level" (`-element -branch -version`) being queried. For example, query for a label using `-element ...` labels are only on versions within elements.

```
cleartool find <path> -element "lbtype_sub(Label b) && ! lbtype_sub(label a) && ! -element (.../Branch1/latest)" -print
```